# Maths book recommendation for two advanced readers

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, reference-request

I want to get a book for my maths teachers. They are both very able: one has a PHD in maths from Cambridge University in the UK, and the other was at the IMO. Because of this, I am unsure of which books are the right difficulty, as the books I do are much easier (e.g. Calculus by Spivak)

One has a particular interest in Analysis, so any recommendation on that would be appreciated. The other specialised in Combinatorics at university, so something along those lines would probably be best. However, any recommendations of books at the right difficulty would be great.

Thank you!!

Edit: having read the comments, I will probably ask them if they have the book before buying it.

Comment: "Proofs from the Book" would likely be a good read for anyone interested in combinatorics. I'm certainly enjoying it since I got it for Christmas this year.

Comment: If this is for a present IMHO is a really bad idea to try to surprise to some one with something related to one of it hobbies or it profession.

Comment: Don't you need a list of books (which could be dozens, maybe even hundreds) that the teacher already owns before picking one? Also, I suspect that unless you REALLY know the teacher's interests well, you're probably not going to be very successful in picking a book they'd be interested in.

Comment: My teacher who is interested in analysis I know to be very interested in it, but did not study it primarily in his degree and PHD, rather taking it up subsequently.

Comment: Although not textbooks, books by N. Taleb  are usually praised by many professors I've met. Though, again, there's a high chance they've already read it.